# How to compare two text files for the same exact text using BASH?

Tags: linux, bash, text, grep, compare

Let's say I have two text files that I need to extract data out of. The text of the two files is as follows:

**File 1:**

```
1name - randomemail@email.com
2Name - superrandomemail@email.com
3Name - 123random@email.com
4Name - random123@email.com
```

**File 2:**

```
email.com
email.com
email.com
anotherwebsite.com
```

File 2 is File 1's list of domain names, extracted from the email addresses.
These are not the same domain names by any means, and are quite random.

How can I get the results of the domain names that match File 2 from File 1?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that order does not matter,

```
grep -F -f FILE2 FILE1
```

should do the trick.  (This works because of a little-known fact: the `-F` option to `grep` doesn't just mean "match this fixed string," it means "match any of these newline-separated fixed strings.")

Comment: You are a life-saver. Thank you! Is there any way we can get this to display it back in the same format such as Name - Email address?

Comment: It will print entire lines from FILE1 that contain any of the strings in FILE2.  Is that not the format you want?

Comment: My mistake! It works fine now! Issue with my formatting. Thank you! :D

Answer (score 2):

The recipe:

```
join <(sed 's/^.*@//' file1|sort -u) <(sort -u file2)
```

it will output the intersection of all domain names in file1 and file2

Answer (score 2):

See [BashFAQ/036](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/036) for the list of usual solutions to this type of problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use VimDIFF command, this gives a nice presentation of difference

Comment: I found it better than `grep -F -f FILE2 FILE1`

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you want to filter for all addresses with the host mentioned in File 2.

You could then just loop over `File 2` and grep for `@<line>`, accumulating the result in a new file or something similar.

Example:

```
cat file2 | sort -u | while read host; do grep "@$host" file1; done > filtered
```

Comment: Correct! But with the Name - Email@ddress format used in File 1. It may seem pointless, but it definitely has a point for me!

Comment: This will read all of file1 for every line in file2. It may get the job done, but it is very inefficient.

Comment: @jordanm Agreed. I'm all for the `grep -f -F` solution. I tried to be conceptual.