# Bash recursive similarities between directories content

Tags: linux, bash, recursion, compare, diff

I am looking for a bash command/script that will do the following:

1. Having two directory structures with different structure and file names
2. To find all lines in one structure that is the same as a line in another file in the other directory structure

E.g. `line 56 "int archiveHex = 0x.." in file1.cpp is the same as same as line 89 of fileArchive.cpp`. Of course the line numbers are not required at that stage the line content is good enought.

Long story is I do have two projects both quite big and I want to see does anyone used GPL code from one of the projects into his commercial product. However names of files and directory structure is changed but I see similarities and I am sure they copied something.

I found this two related questions:

- [How to compare two text files for the same exact text using BASH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12869354/how-to-compare-two-text-files-for-the-same-exact-text-using-bash)
  so it uses GREP but you have to pass the 2 files and cannot work
  recursively.
- Also I found
  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1079/output-the-common-lines-similarities-of-two-text-files-the-opposite-of-diff this as a way to use DIFF but for similarities not differences.
- And also I found for the recursive part this question
  https://askubuntu.com/questions/111495/how-to-diff-multiple-files-across-directories

But anyway I don't know how to combine all of them. How would you do this?

Comment: How many lines do the projects have?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a bit of shell and Awk script. Read all the lines of the first directory's files into an array, then for each input line, see if it is a defined key in the array. (I'm filtering out whitespace lines to reduce false positives. Maybe add empty comments to the filter, too.) The array key is the contents of the line and the array key's value is a string which identifies the source file name and line number. We conveniently receive these as colon-separated values from `grep -nr`:

```
grep -nrv '^[[:space:]]*$' "$srcdir" |
awk -F : 'NR==FNR { a[substr($0, length($1 ":" $2 ":")+1)] = $1 ":" $2; next }
    $0 in a { print FILENAME ":" FNR " matches " a[$0] ":" $0; result=1}
END { exit 1-result }' - $(find "$otherdir" -type f)
```

The Awk script is fundamentally very simple; `NR==FNR` is a common idiom which matches the first input file (here, standard input, the pipe from `grep`) which is where we obtain the values for the array `a`; for subsequent input files, we trigger if the input line is a key in the array. The associative array type of Awk is ideal here.

This assumes that you have no file names with colons or newlines in them. It also assumes that the `find` output is small enough to not trigger an "Argument list too long" error, though if it does, that will be somewhat easier to fix.

Comment: As the demo also illustrates, if the input contains several identical lines, the last one will prevail. Maybe actually skip all these lines, as they already triggered a false positive.